# Mono<ServerResponse> vs Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>> as return type in Java Spring Webflux @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding using `Mono<ServerResponse>` vs `Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>>` as return type please.

I am seeing examples where sometimes, `Mono<ServerResponse>` is used as return type in a functional route from Spring Webflux.

But also seeing examples where sometimes, `Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>>` is used as return type in a Spring functional route.

Moreover, there are many examples where `Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>>` is used in the @Controller, @RequestMapping (Get, Post mapping etc...) as return type.

But there are also few examples with returning `Mono<ServerResponse>`.

May I ask, what is the difference between returning either one please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short of it, as I understand it, is that [`org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) is from the original Spring Mvc Framework package and  [`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerResponse.html) is from the spring Reactive package.

The reactive package has a "compatibility" mode that lets you use the backward compatible `@RestController` annotations and they would generally return a `ResponseEntity` as before.

The Reactive package implementation without the compatibility features use a `Router` and `Handler` and generally return a `ServerResponse`. See [Building a Reactive RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/#initial) for a tutorial from spring.

See also the Spring WebFlux guide, chapters [1.4. Annotated Controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller) for the compatibility reactive way and [1.5. Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) for the functional way.

If you look under the covers at the `Annotated Controllers` code you will see it uses the `Functional Endpoints` code.