# Jackson can't serialize ServerResponse. What about back compatibility?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

`ServerResponse` isn't serialized by Jackson

```java
@RestController
// ...
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> signUp(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User userToSave = userMapper.toUser(userDto);
        User savedUser = userService.doAndSave(
                userService.encodingPassword().andThen(userService.addingDefaultRole()),
                userToSave
        );
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
                savedUser.getUsername(), savedUser.getPassword(), savedUser.getAuthorities()
        );
        Mono<String> jwt = tokenService.generateTokenFor(upat);
        return ServerResponse
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(jwt, String.class);
    }
```

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

I don't recall writing any custom serializers for `ResponseEntity`

This problem occurred exactly after I switched from `Mono<String>` to `Mono<ServerResponse>`. I chose a "prettier" `ServerResponse` class since nested parameterizations make me uncomfortable (`Mono<ResponseEntity<...`)

Some say ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026023/23434786), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780472/23434786)):

> You're not supposed to use it within an annotated controller.

> ServerResponse is meant to be used with WebFlux Handlers and not with RestControllers.

Others say ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65295504/23434786)):

> The reactive package has a "compatibility" mode that lets you use the backward compatible @RestController annotations and they would generally return a ResponseEntity as before.

Is there anything I have to do to turn that compatibility mode on?

Comment: ServerResponse is not intended for this. Either return a `Mono<String>` directly, or use a `Mono<ResponseEntity>`. When using annotated methods as with MVC, returns results as you would have with MVC.